# I don't know if my answer is correct, can you confirm? How to prove?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, factorial

[image]

I'm worried because it seems like this is a solution that puts my thoughts on too much. Do you think this is correct?

How to prove this?

Comment: How'd you get the inequality?

Comment: You forgot the !

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say that the solution "puts your thoughts on too much"

Comment: @hcl No, your solution is not correct.

Comment: The factorial in the denominator means that the denominator gets extremely large extremely quickly, so the terms are actually tending to $0$, not $\infty$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please avoid: titles with nothing to do with the question and unnecessary images.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I was able to solve the problem and it was a good time to think about it. Also, I'll write the title properly in the future. Thanks for the advice. Everyone have a good day

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The sum converges. Note that
$$
\frac{3^n + n}{n!} \leq \frac{3^n + 3^n}{n!}
$$
and apply the ratio test.